# Recovering Deleted Record From Backup

Tags: database, filemaker

I have a fairly beginner-ish question.
Let's say I accidentally delete a record (record, not file) from my FM database.
How do I recover that one record from a backup, rather than just copying all the data in by hand?

I was once shown how to do this using the "Import Record" step, and it simply imported the full record (from a backup) back into my database, but for the life of me I can't remember how it was done.

Sorry if it is a silly question!

Thanks in advance -
S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your backup file. Do a search for your specific record. When you find it, make sure that your found set consists of only the one record.

Keep the file open.

Open your live file. Do an import from the backup file you have open. Only the found set will import, ie. the one record you found earlier.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much for the swift response.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that the imported record will now be the last record in the table, it won't go back to where it used to be.

That is: delete the first record in a table of 100 records; import the record from the backup; it will now be record 100. There is no way to import it back to where it was.

Note also that for most relational databases the deleted record may have had related records that may also need to be re-imported if there were deleted.